# vertical barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want this plot

[image]
I start with this plot

[image]
but when i try limit de axis the plot turns in

[image]

Help Please

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like this, I think. I created a sample data using `iris` since you did not provide a reproducible minimal data. The idea is to use `geom_dumbbell()` in the `SciencePo` package to create lines and dots. Then, adjusting x scale to make space for labels. `geom_text_repel()` helps you to add the labels pretty well. If you are keen, you want to check [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(SciencePo)
library(ggrepel)

### Create a sample data
summarize(group_by(iris, Species),
          petal.width = sum(Petal.Width)) %>%
add_row(Species = "whatever", petal.width = 0) -> temp


ggplot(data = temp, aes(x = petal.width, y = Species)) +
geom_dumbbell(xend = 0 , point.size.r = 0, point.size.l = 3) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max(temp$petal.width) + 10))) +
geom_text_repel(aes(x = petal.width, y = Species, label = petal.width),
                    segment.size = 0,
                    max.iter = 2e3,
                    nudge_x = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are confined to only using ggplot, then one way to do this is plotting as a line graph and adding geom_segment.  I just used some dummy data to demonstrate below.

```
data <- data.frame(tech=c('R','Java','Python'), articles=c(1000,2000,1500))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=tech, y=articles)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=tech, yend=0), color="black") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = articles), hjust = -.5) +
    geom_point(size=3) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 8000)) +
    ylab("Number of Scholarly Articles in 2015") +
    xlab("Analytics Software") +
    ggtitle("2015 Scholarly Articles by Analytics Software") +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! when I change limits = c(0, 3000) the lines dissapear,